# Ubuntu 20.04 fingerprint device disconnect during scan

Tags: login, scanner

I have a Xiaomi air pro 2 laptop running ubuntu 20.04.

It detects my fingerprint device, but after attempting to scan, it disconnects the device. Sometimes it gets further in the scan than others. Afterwards I cannot scan another fingerprint until I restart my laptop as a "scan is already in progress".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What do you have in /var/log/syslog ? And in **dmesg -T** ?

Is a bit complicated if you never used, when you can see the system calls being performed by launching the program with strace.

Cheers